# How to get the AWS IoT custom endpoint in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I want to pass the IoT custom endpoint as an env var to a lambda declared in [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/).

I'm talking about the IoT custom endpoint that lives here:
[image]

How do I get it in context of CDK?

Comment: You want to pass it as environment variable hard-coded or get it using cdk ?

Comment: @AmitBaranes with cdk please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can ref AWS sample code:
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-iot-cqrs-example/blob/master/lib/querycommandcontainers.ts

```
const getIoTEndpoint = new customResource.AwsCustomResource(this, 'IoTEndpoint', {
            onCreate: {
              service: 'Iot',
              action: 'describeEndpoint',
              physicalResourceId: customResource.PhysicalResourceId.fromResponse('endpointAddress'),
              parameters: {
                "endpointType": "iot:Data-ATS"
              }
            },
            policy: customResource.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({resources: customResource.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE})
          });

const IOT_ENDPOINT = getIoTEndpoint.getResponseField('endpointAddress')
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I thought we always need lambdas for custom resources.

Answer (score 2):

For those in the CDK V2:

```
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
...
...
...
// Get the current account IoT-Endpoint 
    const getIoTEndpoint = new cdk.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource(this, 'IoTEndpoint', {
        onCreate: {
            service: 'Iot',
            action: 'describeEndpoint',
            physicalResourceId: cdk.custom_resources.PhysicalResourceId.fromResponse('endpointAddress'),
            parameters: {
            "endpointType": "iot:Data-ATS"
            }
        },
        policy: cdk.custom_resources.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({resources: cdk.custom_resources.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE})
    });     

    
    const IOT_ENDPOINT = getIoTEndpoint.getResponseField('endpointAddress')
    console.log(IOT_ENDPOINT)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only way to recover is by using Custom Resources (Lambda), for example (IoTThing): https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/automating-aws-iot-greengrass-setup-with-aws-cloudformation/